# Go program sleeps forever even after passing short time.Duration

Tags: go, time, channel

I'm trying to build some short of semaphore in Go. Although when when the channel receives the signal it just sleeps forever.

I've tried changing the way to sleep and the duration to sleep, but it stills just stopping forever.

Here a representation of what I've tried:

```
func main() {
    backOffChan := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2)
        backOffChan <- struct{}{}
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-backOffChan:
            d := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
            log.Println("reconnecting in %s", d)
            select {
            case <-time.After(d):
                log.Println("reconnected after %s", d)
                return
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that it just returns after printing the log message and returning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has a number of problems, mainly a tight loop using `for`/`select` that may not allow the other goroutine to ever get to send on the channel. Since the `default` case is empty and the `select` has only one `case`, the whole `select` is unnecessary. The following code works correctly:

```
backOffChan := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    backOffChan <- struct{}{}
}()
for range backOffChan {
    d := time.Duration(10 * time.Millisecond)
    log.Printf("reconnecting in %s", d)
    select {
    case <-time.After(d):
        log.Printf("reconnected after %s", d)
        return
    }
}
```

This will wait until the `backOffChan` gets a message without burning a tight loop.

(Note that this code also addresses issues using `log.Println` with formatting directives - these were corrected to `log.Printf`).

See it in action here: https://play.golang.org/p/ksAzOq5ekrm